# On Form Submit, How do I update another sheet with some of the new information?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms, google-sheets-api

So I am essentially trying to do what Zapier does with it lookup row and update row as needed. I can't use Zapier for our team's purposes because I can't work with the 15 minute ish delay.

1 - User sends data via form to Sheet A.

2 - User then needs to update information in Sheet A by submitting new data to sheet B via another Form.

3 - Data in sheet B is then matched up with row data in sheet A via the "ID".

4 - Sheet B Data then overwrites Sheet A data.

I feel like this should be simple...

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/), [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/), [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) and [Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Form Service

> This service allows scripts to create, access, and modify Google Forms.

Spreadsheet Service

> This service allows scripts to create, access, and modify Google Sheets files.

Triggers and event

> Triggers let Apps Script run a function automatically when a certain event, like opening a document, occurs. Simple triggers are a set of reserved functions built into Apps Script, like the function **`onOpen(e)`**, which executes when a user opens a Google Docs, Sheets, or Forms file.

Using **Form submit** trigger you can catch the form values using [ItemResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response) method, get the details from the previous sheet using [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()). Compare the two sets of values then make neccessary updates.

Hope it helps.